# NHibernate References NotFound.Ignore() is running too many queries

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

In my mapping for a table H when using

`References(x => x.E).Column("E_Code").Nullable().NotFound.Ignore()`;

from one table (H) to another table (E), to give me a many to one relationship I get a query for each instance where the E_Code in the H table does not exist in the E table. How can I reduce the number of queries but still have E set to null if there is no match?

Comment: Could you please post more information for your code??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116354/fluentnhibernate-performance-penalty-when-mapping-reference-with-notfound-ignor